# Loop while true

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have setup two commands in Oncreate and both send data to a bluetooth device. I need the 2nd command to wait for a data string to be received from the 1st command before advancing to the  2nd command. Each command just send a byte to BT.  I tried a while looping true but does not seam to work and hangs on the while true statement. I assume the while true is not letting the handler fire when in the loop. Both commands work fine individually as long as I don't send both.

This is the code in Oncreate with both commands and while true statement

```
    looping=true;

    intByteCount =9;
    GetData(intCommand);        // (Command 1)Send byte to get data on reveiver

    while( looping) {               // Wait add data to be received before next command
        Log.d("TAG", "On Hold ?  ");
    }

     intByteCount=160;           // (command 2)
     GetTitle(intCommand);
```

This is the code in a handler for bluetooth that sets the looping to false once all the bytes have been received.

```
    Handler h = new Handler() {

    @Override
    //  public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        byte[]readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;


        if (intByteCount==9){
        // Data is channel status and Master value
        byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[5];
        System.arraycopy(readBuf, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
        looping=false;
        };
```

The GetTitle and GetData are basically the same
Here is the GetTitle()

```
    private void GetData(int FixtureNumber) {

    Log.d("TAG", "Value  " + intArrayToInt(intArray1));

    intByteCount=9;                         // set to receive 9 bytes

    byte buffer[] = new byte[6];

    buffer[0] = ((byte) 1); // Command (get data)
    buffer[1] = ((byte) Master_value);
    buffer[2] = ((byte) intArrayToInt(intArray1));
    buffer[3] = ((byte) intArrayToInt(intArray2));

    buffer[4] = ((byte) 3);
    buffer[5] = ((byte) 4);

    if (isBTConnected) {

        try {
            mmOutputStream.write(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the final code to get both control data

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            intByteCount =9;
            GetData(intCommand);        // Send byte to get data on reveiver
            //you can use a for here and check if the command was executed or just wait and execute the 2nd command
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); //wait 2 seconds
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            intByteCount=160;           // Sed incoming data byte count
            GetTitle(intCommand);
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Thread and wait x amount of time,  :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //your 1st command

        //you can use a for here and check if the command was executed or just wait and execute the 2nd command
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000); //wait 2 seconds
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //your 2nd command
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Agustin that worked fine. The received data was quick so just a delay will work without the control boolean. Here is the new code.

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            intByteCount =9;
            GetData(intCommand);        // Send byte to get data on reveiver
            //you can use a for here and check if the command was executed or just wait and execute the 2nd command
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); //wait 2 seconds
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            intByteCount=160;           // Sed incoming data byte count
            GetTitle(intCommand);
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently holding up the main thread there, something it is not advised to do. The best option for this is to modify the code so that the second Bluetooth command is done in a function that is called where the looping `== false` code is used.